# Send a text create in textAreaInput to the Google Cloud Storage

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity

After the authentication using a *json file using the`googleCloudStorageR` package, I try to write a text in a `textAreaInput` and send as *txt to my Google Cloud Storage bucket without success. The output is always:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3842
Auto-refreshing stale OAuth token.
Warning: Error in : Path 'NA' does not exist
  [No stack trace available]
```

My example without my credential:

```
# Packages
require(rgdal)
require(shiny)
require(shinythemes)
require(googleCloudStorageR)


# Create the shiny dash
ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("cosmo"),
  titlePanel(title="My Map Dashboard"),  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textAreaInput("text_input","Selected data"),
      actionButton("sendMSG", "Send to server")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("sendMSG")
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output){

  MyMSG <- reactive({
    
    output$text_output <- renderText({input$text_input})
    
  })
  
  # Read text write in the box and send to the server
  
  observeEvent(input$sendMSG, {
    
    filename = function() {
      paste0("MyText",Sys.Date(),".txt",sep="")
    }
    content = function(file) {
      write.table(MyMSG(), file, row.names = F)
    }
    # Send output to Google Cloud Storage
    gcs_get_bucket("forestcloud")
    # *txt files
    all_txt_est <- list.files(pattern="\\.txt$", full.names=TRUE)
    for(f in 1:length(all_txt_est)){
      all_txt_est_name<-all_txt_est[f] 
      gcs_upload(all_txt_est_name, name=all_txt_est_name)
    }
    ###  
 
})
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
##
```

Please, any help for solving it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably `all_txt_est` is empty. You don't execute the `write.table` function in your observer, you just define a function which executes `write.table`, but you don't use this function.

Don't define an `output` slot inside a `reactive` conductor, that makes no sense.

Perhaps the following is what you want. I don't know about Google cloud storage, so I'm not sure the code is correct regarding this point.

```
server <- function(input, output){
    
  output$sendMSG <- renderText({input$text_input}) # you can do that but this will render the same as the textAreaInput
      
  observeEvent(input$sendMSG, {

    filePath <- tempfile(fileext = ".txt")
    writeLines(input$text_input, filePath)
    # Send output to Google Cloud Storage
    gcs_get_bucket("forestcloud")
    gcs_upload(filePath, name = filePath)
 
  })

}
```

Comment: Nice and thanks @Stéphane Laurent problem solved!!!